# DismissViewController not deallocating memory from using cached images. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiimageview

My question title might leave something to be desired, but here's the basic problem:

I present a `UIViewController` that has a `UIScrollView` added to it. Inside the scroll view I layout numerous pre-loaded images using `UIImageView`'s where the images themselves are cached from my image assets. The images are quite large, as they are really good quality. When the `UIViewController` is presented, a lot of memory is allocated to layout the images, but when the VC is dismissed using `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, it seems like all the memory from the VC is deallocated except the memory from the images (which is really most of the memory used).

I've tried storing the images in an array of optional image view's like: `[UIImageView?]`, and then right before calling for the VC to be dismissed, calling `removeFromSuperview` on each one, then setting to `nil`.

The problem is no matter what I do, the memory is never deallocated. How can I ensure that the memory used for these images is properly deallocated when the `UIViewController` is dismissed?

Here's how the `UIImageView`'s are laid out:

```
    for i in 0 ..< preLoadedImageNames.count {

        let contentWidth:CGFloat = min(self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)/3
        let contentHeight:CGFloat = height

        let content:UIView = UIView()
        scroll.addSubview(content)
        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let contentHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentHeight)
        let contentWidthConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth)
        let contentTop:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let contentLeft:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: content, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scroll, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: contentWidth*CGFloat(i))
        scroll.addConstraints([contentHeightConstraint, contentWidthConstraint, contentTop, contentLeft])

        let imageHeight:CGFloat = contentHeight*0.90
        let imageWidth:CGFloat = contentWidth*0.90

        let thumbnail:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        content.addSubview(thumbnail)
        thumbnail.image = UIImage(named: preLoadedImageNames[i])
        thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        thumbnail.frame = CGRect(x: contentWidth/2 - imageWidth/2, y: contentHeight/2 - imageHeight/2, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight)

        images.append(thumbnail)

        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.quickStartTapped(_:)))
        content.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.quickStartTaps.append(tap)

        scroll.contentSize.width += contentWidth

    }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Why is the memory used to layout these images not being deallocated when the view controller is dismissed?

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Have you verified that your view controller is actually being deinited? You can add a `deinit { }` method and be sure.

Comment: @kleezy - That was a good idea...and actually `deinit` is not being called. I have no idea why...

Comment: Look for things such as non-weak references to objects that own your view controller, or blocks that reference self. Things like that can often lead to memory leaks like this. Also, wherever you presented your view controller from, does it still have a variable that references the VC after it's been dismissed?

Comment: @kleezy - Hey I was actually wrong, `deinit` IS being called, it just for some reason won't stop there if I insert a breakpoint, but don't have any actual code executed. So I put a simple `print()` call inside `deinit {}` and now I see that it is actually being called. So the VC is actually being deinitialized, but the memory allocated for these `UIImageView`s isn't being deallocated. I am scratching my head.

Comment: @kleezy - To answer your question, with the VC that presents the view controller with the memory leak, I do have a variable that references it, but it's an optional value that I immediately set to `nil` after dismissal. So it's set up like `var viewController: UIViewController!` and then, after I call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, in the completion block I will say `viewController = nil`

Comment: @Pierce hi, have you resolved this problem?